# Isolate terms within an equation in Maple

Tags: maple

Is it possible to automatically (from command line, or using select and then the menu from right-click of the mouse) to isolate specific terms in an equation withn maple? 
Hier is a very simple simple example example (may equations are way too large):

$\frac{\sqrt{a1-b^2}}{c}+d-e=0$  and say I want to get $\frac{\sqrt{a1-b^2}}{c}=-d+e$

for my equation, I already tried the command `idolate` but it seems not to work very cleverly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "isolate", do you mean you want to get this particular term as an expression?
If you can select it with the mouse, you can copy it either from the right-click menu or by keyboard command (Ctrl+C for Linux or Windows, Command+C for Mac) 
and then paste it into an input line (Ctrl+V for Linux or Windows, Command+V for Mac).

UPDATE:
In your example, you want to use the command "isolate".  Given the equation
(call it "eq"), and your term "term" the command

> isolate(eq, term);

should produce exactly what you asked for:

$$ {\frac {\sqrt {a1 -{b}^{2}}}{c}}=-d+e$$

Please be more explicit about in what sense this "seems not to work very cleverly"/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Please see my update.