# isolate a term within an equation in maple

Tags: maple

This post is inspired by [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/844278/isolate-terms-within-an-equation-in-maple).

Is it possible to isolate a specific term within maple? For example I want to find a/b

I apologize I don't know how to write equation in this forum? So I just too a picture of the maple commands.

[image: Trying to isolate a/b]

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Note that I haven't assigned anything to `term`, below.

```
restart:                                

eq := 2*x + 3*a + y + 7*c = 4*b:        

isolate( algsubs( b=a/term, eq), term );

                                     4 a
                      term = -------------------
                             2 x + 3 a + y + 7 c


4*a/eq; # check

                               4 a
                       ------------------- = a/b
                       2 x + 3 a + y + 7 c
```

Notice also, that there is another "answer",

```
isolate( algsubs( a=b*term, eq), term );

                             4 b - 2 x - y - 7 c
                      term = -------------------
                                     3 b
```

and that can also be obtained in other ways, eg,

```
normal( isolate( expand(eq/b), a/b ) );

                             4 b - 2 x - y - 7 c
                       a/b = -------------------
                                     3 b
```

Which answer do you want? The one that still contains `a`, or the one that still contains `b`?